# How to get data from app.post in react.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
//server.js

app.post('/trip', function(req,res){
  var params = "something";
  getResult(params).then((db)=>{
    // I want to access variable named "db" in App.js(React), but I don't know how to do.
    res.send(db);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

I want to access variable named "db" in App.js(React), but I don't know how to do. If I use axios like

```
//App.js

axios.get('http://localhost:3000/trip').then((response)=>{
  console.log(response.data);
})
```

but "GET http://localhost:3000/trip 404 (Not Found)" prints. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/trip` endpoint is of type `post`, you should be using `axios.post()` instead of `axios.get()`.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/trip',#POST Call Body#)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Refer https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example for more details.